# Flyout menu in UWP with MVVM

Tags: mvvm, uwp, windows-10-universal, flyout

I'm trying to implement a Flyout menu in a Windows 10 App (using MVVM) that opens when holding down an item of a GridView. I've been looking and I haven't been able to find any examples that works for me. The Flyout menu is not opening to display options. Does anyone know how can I do it?

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <Image Source="{Binding Dictionary}" Height="25"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" Width="170"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

**Note:** Solution found in https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/using-a-behavior-to-open-attached-flyouts-in-winows-81-store-apps/

Comment: Where is your code? How can we debug this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to paste it

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to set is StackPanel.Flyout instead of FlyoutBase

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
            </StackPanel.Flyout>
            <Image Source="{Binding Dictionary}" Height="25"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" Width="170"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Alternatively if this doesn't work for you you can target the GridViewItem.Flyout

```
<GridView>
   <GridView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
          <Setter Property="Flyout">
             <Setter.Value>
                <MenuFlyout>
                   <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
             </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
</Gridview.Resources>
```

Comment: I have tried both and I get the following error: The member "Flyout" is not recognized or is not accessible. 

I found a solution by creating an Action: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/using-a-behavior-to-open-attached-flyouts-in-winows-81-store-apps/  Thanks anyway :)